# InvalidArgument = ValueOf 0 is not valid for SelectedIndex

Tags: vba, antivirus

I just installed VBS and getting myself into making FormApllications. I'm making an Anti-Virus Software but I get a problem for ComboBox.
When I run the app, It says:
***System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not >  valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex'***

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrivers)
End Sub
```

Can someone help me understand this? Thanks in Advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your last two lines in the order as shown below. Basically you want to add the items and then select the first item to show.

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrivers)
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: I did that but I get the same message error again. But thanks for answering.

Comment: If that's the case then you are not getting any items added to the combobox. To test this you can change the last line as ComboBox1.SelectedIndex= -1

Comment: Could you please accept it as answer if it helped you. Thanks.